# Ruby mass rename script not finding text or csv for file renaming

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following .rb array script in the same directory as the .png files I want to rename. I ran the script initially and it found the csv and text files and used the lists in those files to rename the .png files. Now for some reason it will not open the .txt file or .csv file to rename the .png files when the script is ran. Receive the error "Can't convert Nil to String". Will ARGV[0] search for any text or csv file in the same directory?

```
open(ARGV[0]).each do |line|
rec = line.strip.split(",")
#arguments are record array
originalName = rec[0]
newName=rec[1]
commandString = `mv '#{originalName}'.png '#{newName}'.png`
puts commandString
puts #{commandString}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will ARGV[0] search for any text or csv file in the same directory?

No, `ARGV[0]` is just the first argument that you pass to the script.

For this script to work it looks like you'll need to run the script with the csv file you want to use as its first argument, and you'll have to be in the directory that contains the files you want renamed.

For example,

```
cd /path/to/png_files
./mass_rename_script.rb file_with_stuff_to_rename.csv
```

Comment: Thank you Ajedi. This is what I was afraid of. Is there a way to have the script search the current directory for any .csv file? I plan to only have one .csv file in the directory.

Comment: If all you want is a quick hack you can probably just replace `ARGV[0]` with `Dir.glob("*.csv").first`. (Note: I haven't tested this.)

Comment: Oh, and if my answer answers your question be sure to click the Accept button (the checkmark) on the left.